# Using YUI, how do I assemble the request using a RecordSet and submit a form to the server?

Tags: forms, yui, postback, submit

Could you please provide me a simple example for assembling the request and sending to the server using the RecordSet? If someone knows how,please post it here.

Also how do I handle the form post-back, any ideas?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

There are two fairly independant parts to this. I generally use something along these lines.

First you want to get all the data from the datatable:

```
    function getAllData(dataTable) {
       var aData = [];
       var aRecs = dataTable.getRecordSet().getRecords();
       for (i=0; i < aRecs.length; i++) {
           aData.push(aRecs[i].getData());
       }
       return(aData)
    }
```

Next you want to post it. Since this is a complex data structure (array of rows of data), it's easiest to just send it encoded as JSON. You can then decode this in save.cgi:

```
    function postDataToServer(aRows) {
        YAHOO.util.Connect.asyncRequest(
            'POST', 'cgi-bin/save.cgi', {
                success: function (o) {
                    // Examine output of save.cgi in o.responseText
                },
                failure: function (o) {
                    // Error text in in o.responseText
                }
            }, "data="+encodeURIComponent(YAHOO.lang.JSON.stringify(aData))
        );
    };
```

The script save.cgi will need to check the value passed the the "data" parameter.